# Staking Contracts

Tags: tokens, proxy-contracts

Is there an ERC token which can provide staking functions?
I have a use case where as a crypto trader I desire to create tokens for issuance in a pool. The members of the pool will purchase the tokens from me and are created at that time, one half issued to me and the other half to the stake holder. These tokens will be held for a set period of time and then redeemed in an extended transaction, which may be renewable. The capital in the pool will be held in various online exchanges and actively traded and invested in the crypto markets. When the contract expires the shares of that contract will be liquidated from the pool or sold to a new stake holder at a fixed price calculated from the pools total assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

ERC is nothing more than a standard that is used to assure compatibility of functionality.

What you want **can** be done through smart contract development, but at this point, it would likely break standards for widely acceptable ERC tokens.